# How To change Color in pie chart with the using of pykcharts library?

Tags: pykcharts

[image]

I Need 10 different Colors in Pie chart Using the Library of pykcharts.
Is it possible Because As per the Documentation they Provide only one `shade_color`.

Go through this link http://pykcharts.com/tour/pie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tkingovr chart_color is for all charts but One dimensional. You can use shade_color for One dimensional charts https://github.com/pykih/PykCharts.js/wiki/Colors#shade-color

@KIRANJOSHI
`var selector = "pieContainer", // selector of your chart
     colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","orange"];
 setTimeout(function() {
     d3.selectAll("#" + selector + "_svg path.pie")
         .attr("fill",function(d, i) {
              return colors[i];
         });
 },1000);`

setTimeout is required since the chart may take time to render and there is no provision in the current version to run a piece of code on chart render complete.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should be able to pass in values like this:

```
 {
   "chart_color": ["blue","green","Yellow"]
 }
```

The chart also accepts any of the following:

```
Color Names (Eg: "red")
Hex values (Eg: "#B0171F")
RGB values (Eg: "rgb(176,23,31)" )
```